# os.walk and some tests

Tags: python, regex, directory

I'm not sure if i understand properly how os.walk store its results.

Im trying to do the following:

I'm checking a root folder for subsequent folders. There are several hundreds of em, and they are nested in somewaht uniform way.

I'm trying to check each subfolder, and if it ends with a four digit number, store it in a list.

I used a highly procedural code, and got to it, but the code is using os.listdir, meaning that i need to execute the function for each folder i want.

Is there a better way?

```
def ListadorPastas(pasta):

    resultado = []

    regex = "^[0-9]{4}"
    padrao = re.compile(regex)

    for p in os.listdir(pasta):
        regexObject = re.match(padrao,p[-4:])
        if (regexObject!=None):
            resultado.append(regexObject.string)
        else:
            pass
    return resultado
```

Also, i have a regex problem: this regex is matching the last four sliced digits of a expression. Sometime i have folders with 5 digits in the end, which ALSO will match. I tried using "$[0-9]{4}" but it returns me nothing. Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance.

George

Comment: Posing just one question per question, instead of two totally unrelated ones (on os.walk and regex) which just happen to concern the same piece of code of yours, would be really much more courteous, making life easier for people trying to answer as well as readers looking for answers in the future (each question can be properly titled and tagged, thus searched for, etc, etc).

Comment: I need to check an infinity of folders, and test if they have four digits in the end. If so, add them to a list. I'm having trouble because my function needs to be repeat in many folders. I was thinking about something more general and automated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> using "$[0-9]{4}" but it returns me
>   nothing. Any ideas why?

`$` means end-of-(line or string) in a regex pattern, so I wonder how you expected "end of string then four digits" to ever possibly match anything...?  By definition of "end" it won't be followed by 4 digits! `r'(^|\D)\d{4}$'` should work better if I understand what you want, to match strings that are just 4 digits, or end with exactly 4 digits, not 5 or more (`\D` means non-digit, just like `\d` means digit -- no reason to use `[0-9]` or `[^0-9]`!).

`os.walk` does not need to store much -- a couple pointers on the implicit tree it's walking -- but why do you care how it's implemented internally?  Just use it...:

```
def ListadorPastas(pasta):
    resultado = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(pasta):
        for d in dirs:
          if (len(d)==4 or len(d)>4 and not d[-5].isdigit()
             ) and d[-4:].isdigit():
              resultado.append(d)
    return resultado
```

where I'm also taking the opportunity to show a non-regex way to do the checks you want on the subdirectory's name.

Answer (score 0):

regex you should be using is:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<!\d)\d{4}$')
re.search(pattern, p)
```

as for `os.walk` your explanation is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

About the regex: If you use `p[-4:]`, you'll always look at the last four characters of `p`, so you don't get a chance to see if there really are five.

So instead, use

```
regex = "(?<![0-9])[0-9]{4}$"
padrao = re.compile(regex)

regexObject = re.search(padrao, p)
```

`re.search` will also match parts of the string.

Comment: Your regex will fail for a string that's exactly 4 digits (nothing before them): you need to accept a nondigit OR start-of-string before the 4 digits-then-end-of-string (see my answer for details on this and more).

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too right after I posted it - just corrected it because it also returns a different-length match object. Now, with lookbehind, it should behave like the poster's solution (but meet the requirement "only four digits")